# What is the Vagrant syntax for adding a locally existing VDI?

Tags: vagrant, file-uri, uri-scheme

What is the syntax for adding a locally existing VirtualBox .vdi to vagrant?

There doesn't appear to be an example of alternate URI schemes in the documentation.

Can it also use ssh and httpauth locations?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You cannot directly "import" a VirtualBox VM into Vagrant.

Basically you'll have to package the existing VirtualBox VM to a `box` and then add it to vagrant.

> NOTE: a box is tarred VirtualBox Exports (could be gzipped).

You would be doing

### Package the existing VirtualBox VM (VDI format)

`vagrant package --base mybox --output /path/to/mybox.box`

See more here `=>` http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/package.html

### Add the box to vagrant

`vagrant box add mybox /path/to/mybox.box`

Comment: I eventually found that in the documentation. It could be more prominent though.